# na.rm is not working and cannot calculate the mean

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the mean of every city that has positive covid tests over 50,000. When I try the following code:

```
covidJoined %>% group_by(Admin2) %>% filter(numOfCases > 50000) %>% slice(which.max(numOfCases)) %>% mean(as.numeric(covidJoined$Population), na.rm = TRUE)
```

I get the following error: argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

How can i fix this?

```
summary(covidJoined)
    Admin2               Lat            Long_            date             numOfCases       Population     
 Length:15240       Min.   : 0.00   Min.   :-123.9   Length:15240       Min.   :     0   Min.   :   1175  
 Class :character   1st Qu.:36.44   1st Qu.:-122.0   Class :character   1st Qu.:     1   1st Qu.:  45578  
 Mode  :character   Median :37.98   Median :-120.8   Mode  :character   Median :    77   Median : 179140  
                    Mean   :36.58   Mean   :-116.7                      Mean   :  4108   Mean   : 642310  
                    3rd Qu.:39.20   3rd Qu.:-119.8                      3rd Qu.:  1389   3rd Qu.: 685306  
                    Max.   :41.74   Max.   :   0.0                      Max.   :271371   Max.   :9818605  
                                                                                         NA's   :508



 str(covidJoined)
tibble [15,240 x 6] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Admin2    : chr [1:15240] "Alameda" "Alameda" "Alameda" "Alameda" ...
 $ Lat       : num [1:15240] 37.6 37.6 37.6 37.6 37.6 ...
 $ Long_     : num [1:15240] -122 -122 -122 -122 -122 ...
 $ date      : chr [1:15240] "1/22/20" "1/23/20" "1/24/20" "1/25/20" ...
 $ numOfCases: num [1:15240] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Population: num [1:15240] 1510271 1510271 1510271 1510271 1510271 ...
```

Comment: The issue is not `na.rm`. The issue is that you are passing a data.frame to mean. I guess you want something like `summarise(mean(as.numeric(Population), na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: Hi stephan!  I am getting 1 Los Angeles 9818605 2 Orange 3010232 3 Riverside 2189641 4 San Bernardino 2035210 I would like to get the mean of these 4

Comment: That's because your df is grouped. Add an `ungroup` before summarising.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
covidJoined %>%
  filter(numOfCases > 50000) %>%
  group_by(Admin2) %>%
  summarise(avg_Pop = mean(Population))
```

Comment: Hi Alex!  I am getting                                                                                                        1 Los Angeles                                         9818605
2 Orange                                              3010232
3 Riverside                                           2189641
4 San Bernardino                                      2035210           I would like to get the mean of these 4

Comment: Remove the `group_by()` line if you want an overall mean.